# Can't add capabilities and upload app to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I am developing an iOS game, that will be published by another company. That company already registered bundle ID, generated app on iTunes connect, and given me a **developer** role on their account. I have full access to the app on iTunes connect. The problem is, when I am trying to add capabilities to my app in xcode. For example. When i try to enable in-app purchase I will get a warning like "cannot add in-app purchase to your app id". Same for other capabilities.

Is this issue connected to certificates? Should that company give me any extra access to be able to upload builds to iTunes connect ?

Comment: You need to communicate with your client for this...I think it needs full access like admin...